# is there any difference between TryUpdate() and Update() method in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

is there any difference between `TryUpdate()` and `Update()` method in MVC 5? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `UpdateModel`, if it has any issues while binding properties it will throw an exception, informing that there was a binding error.

Whereas `TryUpdateModel` does not throw an exception if there are any binding errors, instead it logs the error in the model state dictionary, which you can check using `ModelState.IsValid` property.

Nicely explained here - 
http://codetunnel.io/aspnet-mvc-tryupdatemodel-vs-updatemodel/